# converting images to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying to convert a set of images into a movie using ffmpeg. I have a list of files (only 20) in a seperate folder named for image####.png, I tried this command to convert them all to a movie:

`ffmpeg -y -framerate 1 -i .\folder\*.png -vf -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4`

and i get this error
`Could find no file with path '.\folder\*.png' and index in the range 0-4`

I found some suggestings to use -start_number and renaming the files to '0000.png' in sequence. I have tried both, but i am still getting the same error message. Even running the command from within the folder, still gets the same error.

Can anyone help resolve this?

Comment: Maybe try to eliminate potential sources of problems, such as hoping that Windows paths will work. Try `cd folder && ffmpeg -y -framerate 1 -i *.png ...`

Comment: I've previously used `-pattern_type glob -i '*.png'` - as with Mark Setchell's comment I did that in the same folder as the images, and output to the parent directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestiong @MarkSetchell and GregHNZ but as i indicated in the question, i had already tried it from within the same directory. Even with your simplified versions of the command, i stil get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but it looks like you are on windows, and I think the posix style globbing doesnt work there.

You may need to try .\folder\image%%04d.png

What ffmpeg is looking for is image%04d.png (using printf notation), but you may need to do two %% to escape the %.

Also watch for color space shifts, you may be better off with something like:

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -start_number 1 -i inputfile.%%04d.png -sws_flags area+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int  -pix_fmt yuv420p \
        -vf "scale=in_color_matrix=bt709:out_color_matrix=bt709" \
        -frames:v 100 -c:v libx264 -preset slower \
        -color_range tv -colorspace bt709 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc iec61966-2-1 \
       -movflags faststart outputfile.mp4
```

See https://academysoftwarefoundation.github.io/EncodingGuidelines/Quickstart.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to assign the folder and file paths, try replacing the single quotes with double quotes. It worked for me.